# Setting vars in jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting a few vars in JavaScript. I typically like to make my code really readable so that it's easy to go back and edit.  I have a few questions about the code below:

1) Is this is a good way to break up the setting of the vars?  The comment seems redundant, but it seems to really help break up the code into relevant chunks.

2) When I set a var like this ~~ $IPPWrapper = $("div.iqPaginItemsPerPageWrapper") ~~ I always include the HTML element, in this case the "div".  Is this overkill? Is there a performance hit or benefit? I know in the CSS best practices, it's frowned upon.

3) I need to create an array, but I don't know the best type to use. Basically, I am just storing messages that I will use later in popups.  Is there a more common or better way to create this array?

Thanks in advance for any advice or helpful comments.

```
// GENERAL VARS
var UpRate = 250,
    DownRate = UpRate,
    OpenHeight = "25px";

// SET IPP VARS
var $IPPWrapper = $("div.iqPaginItemsPerPageWrapper"),
    $IPPDefault = $IPPWrapper.children("div.iqPaginDefault"),
    $IPPNonDefault = $IPPWrapper.children("div.iqPaginNonDefault"),
    $IPPOptions = $IPPWrapper.children("div.ItemsPerPage"),
    $IPPValue = $("span#ItemsPerPageValue");

// SET SB VARS
var $SBWrapper = $("div.iqPaginSortByWrapper"),
    $SBDefault = $SBWrapper.children("div.iqPaginDefault"),
    $SBNonDefault = $SBWrapper.children("div.iqPaginNonDefault"),
    $SBOptions = $SBWrapper.children("div.SortBy"),
    $SBValue = $("span#SortByValue");

// CREATE SB TEXT ARRAY
var SBTextArray = new Array();
    SBTextArray[1] = "Company Name A - Z";
    SBTextArray[2] = "Company Name Z - A";
    SBTextArray[3] = "Product Name A - Z";
    SBTextArray[4] = "Product Name Z - A";
    SBTextArray[5] = "Model Number A - Z";
    SBTextArray[6] = "Model Number Z - A";
```

EDIT ~~ Is this a better way of coding the above array?

```
// CREATE SB TEXT ARRAY
var SBTextArray = [ 
        "Company Name A - Z", "Company Name Z - A",
        "Product Name A - Z", "Product Name Z - A",
        "Model Number A - Z", "Model Number Z - A",
    ];
```

Comment: don't use `new Array()` go for the array literal `var SBTextArray = ["Company Name A - Z","Company Name Z - A", ....];` [read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094723/what-is-array-literal-notation-in-javascript-and-when-should-you-use-it)

Comment: @rlemon, thanks for the link. I have this correct now, right?

Comment: yes, the array is now zero index'd - if you want to set the keys you will use an object. Arrays should be zero index'd in js.

Comment: You can test for performance yourself - check out [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Your code is great so far.
The only tip I can think of is to wrap grouped variables inside a namespace / singleton.
This would make it easier to debug and perform operations of group of related elements.

```
    // GENERAL VARS
var UpRate = 250,
    DownRate = UpRate,
    OpenHeight = "25px";

// SET IPP VARS
var $IPP = {};
$IPP.Wrapper = $("div.iqPaginItemsPerPageWrapper");
$IPP.Default = $IPP.Wrapper.children("div.iqPaginDefault");
$IPP.NonDefault = $IPP.Wrapper.children("div.iqPaginNonDefault");
$IPP.Options = $IPP.Wrapper.children("div.ItemsPerPage");
$IPP.Value = $("span#ItemsPerPageValue");

// SET SB VARS
var $SB = {};
$SB.Wrapper = $("div.iqPaginSortByWrapper");
$SB.Default = $SB.Wrapper.children("div.iqPaginDefault");
$SB.NonDefault = $SB.Wrapper.children("div.iqPaginNonDefault");
$SB.Options = $SB.Wrapper.children("div.SortBy");
$SB.Value = $("span#SortByValue");

// CREATE SB TEXT ARRAY
var SBTextArray = [];
SBTextArray[1] = "Company Name A - Z";
SBTextArray[2] = "Company Name Z - A";
SBTextArray[3] = "Product Name A - Z";
SBTextArray[4] = "Product Name Z - A";
SBTextArray[5] = "Model Number A - Z";
SBTextArray[6] = "Model Number Z - A";
```

1) Use a namespace for related elements and functionality.

2) It depends. In most cases it doesn't matter unless if you different tags with the same classes. Like `p.class1` and `dd.class1`. More info [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/15-powerful-jquery-tips-and-tricks-for-developers/)

3) You could just use an object literal to store the message by a reference name.
Something like this.

```
var listing = { az: {}, za: {} };
listing.az.company = "Company Name A - Z";
listing.az.product = "Product Name A - Z";
listing.az.model = "Model Number A - Z";
listing.za.company = "Company Name Z - A";
listing.za.product = "Product Name Z - A";
listing.za.model = "Model Number Z - A";
```

I think your current code is good enough though.

Comment: Larry, that looks interesting. Do you have a link to a good article on the concept of using the namespace like you are using?

Comment: "Namespacing in javascript" http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/

Answer (score 1):

In javascript notmally Classes are `CamelCase` constants are `ALLCAPS`

These look like constants to me:

```
// GENERAL VARS
var UpRate = 250,
    DownRate = UpRate,
    OpenHeight = "25px";
```

and as such I would change them to all caps

```
// GENERAL VARS
var UPRATE = 250,
    DOWNRATE = UPRATE,
    OPENHEIGHT = "25px";
```

Some people like `CONSTANTS_WITH_UNDERSCORES` and some don't. That's really up to you but this way allows you to easily distinguish between classes and constants.

Regular variables

```
var $IPPWrapper = $(....

var SBTextArray = [ ... ] ;
```

should either be `$lowerCase` or just `lowerCase`. Something like:

```
var $ippWrapper = $(....

var sbTextArray = [ ... ] ;
```